Selecting and loading a *.json file using Expo DocumentPicker in older versions of Android
In React Native Expo project, I am using Expo DocumentPicker to select a JSON file and load it into the application.
On modern version of Android there is no problem with this, in file explorer I select the desired JSON file and upload it.  But on older versions of Android( 7, 8) I can't select the JSON file, I can see it in file explorer but it is not available for selection.
If I remove type: 'application/json', I can select json file, but other file types are also available for selection.
  const uploadJsonFile = async () => {
    try {
      const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
        type: 'application/json',
      });
      setUploadedBackup(file.assets);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

How can I solve this problem?  I can find out the Android version and if the version is below a certain value not specify the file type to select.  But from which Android version there is no problem with selecting 'application/json'?
Update
I've come to this decision :
import * as mime from 'react-native-mime-types';
import * as Device from 'expo-device';

 const androidVersion = Device.osVersion;

  const uploadJsonFile = async () => {
    const fileMimeType = Number(androidVersion) < 12 ? 'application/octet-stream' : 'application/json';

    try {
      const file = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
        type: fileMimeType,
      });

      if (!file.assets) return;

      const mimeType = mime.lookup(file.assets[0].uri);

      if (
        file.assets &&
        mimeType === 'application/json' &&
        file.assets[0].name.startsWith('app-name-file')
      ) {
        setUploadedBackup(file.assets);
      } else {
        showToast(t('wrongFileType'));
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

